# Image Water mark on Image in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am a beginner in tkinter and I'm trying to add a logo onto the background of an image but I am not getting the expected result. I also nee to transparent the logo. Here's what I have for the code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def watermark(file,result_image):
    logo_image = Image.open(file)
    background_image = Image.open(initialdir='Users\picture')

    logo_width, logo_height = logo_image.size
    background_width, background_height = background_image.size

    if logo_width > background_width or logo_height > background_height:
        logo_image = logo_image.resize((background_width, background_height))

    result_image = Image.new('RGBA', background_image.size)
    result_image.paste(background_image,(0,0))

    logo_x = 0
    logo_y = 0

    result_image.paste(logo_image, (logo_x,logo_y), mask=logo_image)
    result_image.show()

def open_file():
    file=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='Users\picture') 

def open_filelogo():
    file2=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='Users\picture')

window=Tk()
window.title("Water Mark APP")
window.geometry('500x400')

lable=Label(text="Select the image",font=("Arial", 25))
lable.pack()
lable.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)

Button1=Button(text="Select Image",command=open_file)
Button1.pack()
Button1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=SE)

Button2=Button(text="Select Image Logo",command=open_filelogo)
Button2.pack()
Button2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=NW)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction of the code you provided:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def watermark(image_path, logo_path):
    background_image = Image.open(image_path)
    logo_image = Image.open(logo_path).convert("RGBA")

    max_logo_size = (200, 200)  # Adjust the size as needed
    logo_image.thumbnail(max_logo_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    result_image = Image.new('RGBA', background_image.size)
    result_image.paste(background_image, (0, 0))

    logo_x = result_image.width - logo_image.width - 10  # Adjust the position as needed
    logo_y = result_image.height - logo_image.height - 10  # Adjust the position as needed

    result_image.paste(logo_image, (logo_x, logo_y), mask=logo_image.split()[3])

    # Display the result in a Tkinter window
    window = Toplevel()
    window.title("Watermarked Image")
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(result_image)
    label = Label(window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo
    label.pack()

def open_file():
    image_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/Users/picture') 
    open_filelogo()

    def open_filelogo():
        logo_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/Users/picture')
        watermark(image_path, logo_path)

window = Tk()
window.title("Water Mark APP")
window.geometry('500x400')

label = Label(text="Select the image", font=("Arial", 25))
label.pack()
label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)

Button1 = Button(text="Select Image", command=open_file)
Button1.pack()
Button1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=SE)

window.mainloop()
```

It may work or may not

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the support. It still not working actually i need one button that open logo image file and 2nd button that can open test image file and then by pressing third button I may get the logo-image combination.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to do:

- avoid wildcard import
- make the two variables `file` and `file2` global variables, otherwise they cannot be accessed outside the functions
- make sure that the two images have transparency by using `.convert("RGBA")` on them
- use `.thumbnail()` to keep the aspect ratio when resizing the logo image
- create the third button to show the result image

Below is the modified code:

```py
# avoid wildcard import
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# initialize global variables
file = file2 = None

def watermark():
    # make sure both images are selected
    if file and file2:
        # make sure the loaded images support transparency
        logo_image = Image.open(file2).convert("RGBA")
        background_image = Image.open(file).convert("RGBA")

        logo_width, logo_height = logo_image.size
        background_width, background_height = background_image.size

        if logo_width > background_width or logo_height > background_height:
            # Use thumbnail() to keep the image aspect ratio
            logo_image.thumbnail((background_width, background_height))

        logo_x = 0
        logo_y = 0

        background_image.paste(logo_image, (logo_x, logo_y), mask=logo_image)
        background_image.show()

def open_file():
    global file
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='Users/picture')

def open_filelogo():
    global file2
    file2 = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='Users/picture')

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Water Mark APP")
window.geometry('500x400')

label = ttk.Label(window, text="Select the image", font=("Arial", 25))
label.pack()

button1 = ttk.Button(window, text="Select Image", command=open_file)
button1.pack()

button2 = ttk.Button(window, text="Select Image Logo", command=open_filelogo)
button2.pack()

# create third button to show the watermark image
button3 = ttk.Button(window, text="Show Watermark Image", command=watermark)
button3.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Note also that using both `.pack()` and `.place()` on the same widget are not necessary as the later will override the former.  My code uses `.pack()` only on those widgets.

Comment: On line 40, typo error `ttk.Label(window.` should be `ttk.Label(window,`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the support. another thing is the output image is opening in photo editor app and when i trying to save it in particular location it is not saving as image file or any other format. What we can do for that?

Comment: If you cannot save the image in the photo editor, then it is not related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to add a logo onto the background of an image but I am not
> getting the expected result. I also need to transparent the logo.

Comment out button.pack(),  if you want to use button.place() and vice-versa.

Try to understand how to use `rely`. Start from 0.1, 0.2, 0.25 and so on, But don't we set values too high?

- Don't use wildcard import *
- Add lines 6 and 7 to declare variables. `logo_path = None` and
  `image_path= None`
- On line 11, replace the `file` with the `logo_path`. If persisted,
  then add `global`.
- On line 112, replace the `Image.open(initialdir='Users\picture')` with the `Image.open(image_path)`. If persisted,
  then add `global`.
- On line 36, add `global image_path` to the `open_file()` function.
- On line 40, add `global logo_path` to the `open_filelogo()` function.
- Create `Button` widget to show the display watermark.

Snippet uses the same script but with slightly minor changes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog 
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw,Image, ImageTk
 

logo_path = None
image_path= None


def watermark(file,result_image):
    logo_image = Image.open(logo_path) 
    background_image = Image.open(image_path)
     
    logo_width, logo_height = logo_image.size
    background_width, background_height = background_image.size

    if logo_width > background_width or logo_height > background_height:
        logo_image = logo_image.resize((background_width, background_height))

    result_image = Image.new('RGBA', background_image.size)
    result_image.paste(background_image,(0,0))

    logo_x = 0
    logo_y = 0
    result_image.paste(logo_image, (logo_x, logo_y), mask=logo_image.split()[3])

    # Display the result in a Tkinter window
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    window.title("Watermarked Image")
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(result_image)
    label = tk.Label(window, image=photo)
    label.image = photo
    label.pack()

def open_file():
    global image_path
    image_path=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='Users\picture') 

def open_filelogo():
    global logo_path    
    logo_path=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='Users\picture')

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Water Mark APP")
window.geometry('500x400')

lable = tk.Label(text="Select the image",font=("Arial", 25))
#lable.pack()
lable.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor=tk.CENTER)

Button1 = tk.Button(text="Select Image",command=open_file)
#Button1.pack()
Button1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=tk.SE)

Button2 = tk.Button(text="Select Image Logo",command=open_filelogo)
#Button2.pack()
Button2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, anchor=tk.SE)

button3 = tk.Button(text="Show Watermark Image", command=lambda:watermark(image_path, logo_path))
#button3.pack()
button3.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=tk.SE)

 
window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]